# how to get more than one column using createcrieteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I am having a domain class and i want to query only some fields. How do i do this using create criteria.

I am using this criteria, this works but how do i get another column in output??

```
def cartitem=CartOrder.createCriteria().listDistinct{
                eq("id",cartid)
                vendorproductinfo
                {
                    eq('vendor',vendor)
                    projections{
                        property("productItem") 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting the `productItem` column in the results because of this projection:

```
projections{
  property("productItem") 
}
```

If you want the whole `CartOrder` object to be returned, just remove this:

```
def cartitem = CartOrder.createCriteria().listDistinct {
  vendorproductinfo {
    eq('vendor', vendor)
  }
}
```

### Update

Based on your comment below, it seems that what you actually want in the results are `Vendorproductinfo.productItem` and `Vendorproductinfo.price`. If you don't want any of the fields of the `CartOrder`, then I think you can remove it from the query completely.

Something like the following should work (though I'm not 100% sure that I understand what you're after):

```
def results = Vendorproductinfo.createCriteria().listDistinct {
  eq('vendor', vendor)
  projections{
    property("productItem") 
    property("price") 
  }      
}
```

Comment: the vendorproductinfo also has a field called price i also want that field to be in output along with productitem but not the complete CartOrder object.

Comment: @saurabh - why do you want just few properties and not whole object ! May be you are concerned about performance ? Believe me that won't be a big performance hit.

Comment: @Don The cartorder domain has 1:m relationship with vendorproductinfo, the vendor productinfo has _vendor_,productItem and price fileds. I have the cartorder object and a vendor id and now i want to get all the vendorproductinfo objects which have vendor as _vendor_

Comment: @saurabh can you add the relevant domain classes to your question?